# How do I add data- attributes to Html.BeginForm

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.beginform

I use the following to create a form to upload images on a mobile site.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form/", "Quote", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

However as it is using jQuery mobile, I have enabled Ajax so that transition between pages is nice and smooth.  This has caused the problem that my form won't upload the images as you cannot do file uploads with ajax.  I need to add the attribute `data-ajax="false"` to this form in order for it to allow my file uploads.

Does anyone know how I do this as I tried multiple variations of the following but couldn't get it to work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form/", "Quote", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", "data-ajax" = "false" }))
```

Comment: Could you try `@data-ajax = "false"`, please?

Comment: @AndreCalil I tried that as one of my many variations

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The trick is to use the underscore instead of the hyphen:

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", data_ajax = "false" }
```

The hyphen is not allowed as part of a c# identifier. The MVC framework translates the underscore automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was thinking to come up with a way to translate `_` to `-` but thought I'd do a quick search for the "right" way first. Razor engine, you do love me!

Answer (score 21):

You can use another overload:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Quote", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "enctype", "multipart/form-data" }, { "data-ajax", "false"} }))
```

Comment: while there is more junk { } in this one, it works great for Vue if you need to add a ref attribute to a form since ref is a keyword in C# and cannot work for the "object htmlAttributes" overload.