# Upload File using form not posting the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, file-upload

```
    <form id="UploadForm" action="UploadFileServer.axd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
        <div class="folderSelectorCont">
            <div class="select_file_ttl">${resource.upload_file_Select_File}:</div>
            <div class="folderNameInputArea">

                <button class="select_file_btn" id="choose_file">Select</button>
                <input type="file" class="hidden_input" id="file"/> 
                <label class="chosen_folder" id="file_name" title=""></label>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popButtonsCont">
            <a class="dialogBtns" onclick="hideDialog(); return false;">${resource.manageFolder_cancel}</a>
            <a class="dialogBtns" id="createBtn">${resource.manageFolder_ok}</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

UploadFileServer.axd:

```
    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {

        HttpFileCollection uploadFile = ctx.Request.Files;
        if (uploadFile.Count > 0)
        {
                      //do something


        ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        ctx.Response.Write(uploadFileResponse);
    }
```

but I get uploadFile.Count = 0.
why?

Comment: Are you using any javascript libraries in your page?

Comment: I am specifically wondering if you are using jQuery mobile as this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16575329/1346943) fixed a similar issue when the OP was using jQuery mobile.

Comment: Yes I am using jquery mobile

Comment: Not helping, now it is not getting to the server side at all

Comment: It isn't getting to the server once you added `data-ajax=false` to your form?

Comment: @ledbutter Thank you so much! The problem was the jquery mobile as you said. I can mark your answer because you wrote it as a comment. I added $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; when the application is loaded and not mobile.

Comment: I added an official answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, jQuery mobile has been known to cause problems in this scenario, see this other question as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575329/1346943). Update your config to turn off ajax for jQuery mobile and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When posting form data, controls must have a name attribute as data is sent in name-value pairs, so first off try adding a name to your input:

```
<input type="file" class="hidden_input" id="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

As this guy pointed out: http://www.prolistingservice.com/theblog/post/HttpFileCollection-Always-Zero.aspx

Excerpt:

> Every site I found said there were 2 things you needed to get the HttpFileCollection to populate.
>
> 1) Make sure the form method is "POST"
>   2) Make sure the form enctype is "multipart/form-data"
>
> The AjaxFileUpload code dutifully had this right, however there is one more thing that > ASP.NET needs.
>
> 3) The HTML file input must have a "name" attribute.

I've created a test project with the code you provided, have registered the HttpHandler and it worked once I added the "name" attribute to the input element.

Here is the code, notice the **name** attribute being added into the *input* element:

**Web.config:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="uploadHandler" path="UploadFileServer.axd" verb="*" type="FileUploadHandler.IISHandler1, FileUploadHandler" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**The HTTP Handler:**

```
namespace FileUploadHandler
{
    public class IISHandler1 : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
        {

            HttpFileCollection uploadFile = ctx.Request.Files;
            string uploadFileResponse = "no count";
            if (uploadFile.Count > 0)
            {
                uploadFileResponse = "count > 0";
            }

            ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            ctx.Response.Write(uploadFileResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

**The page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="UploadForm" action="UploadFileServer.axd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
        <div class="folderSelectorCont">
            <div class="select_file_ttl">${resource.upload_file_Select_File}:</div>
            <div class="folderNameInputArea">

                <button class="select_file_btn" id="choose_file">Select</button>
                <input type="file" class="hidden_input" id="file" name="file"/> 
                <label class="chosen_folder" id="file_name" title=""></label>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popButtonsCont">
            <a class="dialogBtns" onclick="hideDialog(); return false;">${resource.manageFolder_cancel}</a>
            <a class="dialogBtns" id="createBtn">${resource.manageFolder_ok}</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks asm00, but I tried and it didn't help, can you please show me your test code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your example and explanation. The problem was the jquery mobile .js file.